# UML Diagram Interpretation in Qt

Tags: qt, uml

Question...

I am trying to interpret this UML Diagram using Qt:
 My concerns are how to define the QList class and how to implement the aggregation and composition relationships. I understand that inheritance is implemented by .... class derived : public base directive.

[image]
 I have posted by attempt below.
May anyone assist. Thanks

```
#ifndef PRODUCT_H
#define PRODUCT_H

#include <Transaction.h>
#include <QString>
#include <QList>
#include <QDate>
#include <QDebug>

//define product class
class Product {
public:
  Product(QString name, int num, double seprice, double suprice, QString sc );
  virtual void sell(int n);
  void restock(int n);
  QString getSupplierCode();
  void setProductCode(QString c );
  QString getProductCode();
  QList<Transaction*>getTransactions();
  QString toString();
  void removeAll();
  bool isExpired();

private:
  QString m_Name;
  int m_NumOfItems;
  QString m_ProductCode;
  double m_SellingPrice;
  double m_SupplierPrice;
  QString m_SupplierCode;
  QList<Transaction*>m_Transactions;

};
//end of product class
#endif //PRODUCT_H

#ifndef FOODPRODUCT_H
#define FOODPRODUCT_H

//begining of FoodProduct class
class FoodProduct : public Product {
public:
  FoodProduct(QString name, int num, double seprice, double suprice, QString sc, QDate sbd);
  void sell(int n);
  QString toString();
  bool isExpired();

private:
  QDate m_SellByDate;

};
//end of FoodProduct Class

#endif // FOODPRODUCT_H

#ifndef PRODUCTLIST_H
#define PRODUCTLIST_H

//begining of ProductList Class
class ProductList : public QList<Product*> {
public:
  QString add(QString name, int num, double seprice, double suprice, QString sc, QDate sbd );
  void sell(QString pc, int n );
  void restock(QString pc, int n );
  QString toString();
  void removeStock();
  QString getTransactions(QString pc) const;

private:
  int m_NextCode;
};
//end of ProductList Class
#endif //PRODUCTLIST_H

#include <Product.h>
#ifndef TRANSACTION_H
#define TRANSACTION_H

//begining of Transaction Class
class Transaction
{
public:
  Transaction(QString type, QDate date, int num, double price );
  QString toString();

private:
  QString m_Type;
  QDate m_Date;
  int m_NoOfItems;
  double m_PricePerItem;

};
//end of Transaction class
#endif // TRANSACTION_H

implementations

#include <Product.h>

Product::Product(QString name, int num, double seprice, double suprice, QString sc)
{
    m_Name = name;
    m_NumOfItems = num;
    m_SellingPrice = seprice;
    m_SupplierPrice = suprice;
    m_SupplierCode = sc;
}

void Product::sell(int n)
{
  if(m_NumOfItems == 0)
  {
    qDebug() << "Out of stock";
  }
  else
    {
        m_NumOfItems -= n;
        m_Transaction.append(Transaction("Sale", QDate::currentDate(),n, m_SellingPrice));
    }
}

void Product::restock(int n)
{
    m_NumOfItems += n;
    m_Transaction.append(Transaction("Purchase", QDate::currentDate(),n, m_SupplierPrice));
}

QString Product::getSupplierCode()
{
    return m_SupplierCode;
}

void Product::setProductCode(QString c)
{
    m_ProductCode = c;
}

QString Product::getProductCode()
{
    return m_ProductCode;
}


QString Product::toString()
{
    return QString("Product Name: %1\nProduct Code: %2\nSupplier Price: %3\nSelling Price: %4\nSupplier Code: %5")
                   .arg(m_Name).arg(m_ProductCode).arg(m_SupplierPrice).arg(m_SellingPrice).arg(m_SupplierCode);
}

void Product::removeAll()
{
    m_NumOfItems = 0;
}

-------------------------

#include <Transaction.h>


Transaction::Transaction(QString type, QDate date, int num, double price)
{
    m_Type = type;
    m_Date = date;
    m_NoOfItems = num;
    m_PricePerItem = price;
}

QString Transaction::toString()
{
   QString date1;
   date1 = m_Date.toString();
   return QString("Transaction Type: %1\nDate: %2\nNumber of Items: %3\nPrice: R%4\n")
        .arg(m_Type).arg(date1).arg(m_NoOfItems).arg(m_PricePerItem*m_NoOfItems);
}

--------------------------

FoodProduct::FoodProduct(QString name,int num, double seprice, double suprice, QString sc, Qdate sbd)
{
    FoodProduct = Product();
    m_SellByDate = sbd;
}

void FoodProduct::sell(int n)
{
    if (isExpired())
        qDebug << "Product has expired!";
    else Product::sell(n);
}

bool FoodProduct::isExpired()
{
    return(m_SellByDate < QDate::currentDate());
}

QString FoodProduct::toString()
{
    Product::toString();
}


--------------------

#include ProductList.h

QString ProductList::add(QString name, int num, double seprice, double suprice, QString sc, QDate sbd)
:int m_NextCode(1001);
{
     ProductList = Product();
     m_SellByDate = sbd;
     m_NextCode++;

}

ProductList::~ProductList()
{

}

void ProductList:sell(Qstring pc, int n)
{
     foreach(Product* pc, ProductList)
    {
        ProductList::m_NumberOfItems -= n;

    }    

}

void ProductList:restock(Qstring pc, int n)
{
     foreach(Product* pc, ProductList)
    {
        ProductList::m_NumberOfItems += n;

    }    

}

void ProductList::removeStock()
{
     foreach(Product* pc, ProductList)
    {
        if (ProductList::isExpired())

        ProductList::m_NumberOfItems = 0;

    } 

}

QString ProductList::toString()
{
     return QString("Product Name: %1\nProduct Code: %2\nNumber of Items: %3")
        .arg(ProductList::m_Name).arg(ProductList::m_ProductCode).arg(ProductList::m_NumberofItems);

}

QString ProductList::getTransactions(QString pc)
{

}
```

Comment: Where is the UML, please? I won't read that long text above.

Comment: Thanks may I send it via email, I dont see how to attach an image here? It tells me I need 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: Place it on a public server (e.g. imageshack.us) and post the link. Once you  got reputation (soon) you can post pictures directly.

Comment: https://db.tt/aIIMyn5E   shared via dropbox

Comment: Ok. So what are your concerns?

Comment: My concerns are how to define the QList<Product*> class and how to implement the aggregation and composition relationships. I understand that inheritance is implemented by .... class derived : public base directive.

Comment: Can you please put that in your question. I'll take the down vote and have a look later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `QList` must not be implemented as itself. It is a generic class and `ProductList` does implement it. It is there to show that the subclass `ProductList` returns a list of `Product` classes.

Regarding aggregation/composition you are rather free on how to implement it. The simplest would be to use an array. You can also use linked lists or whatever is appropriate. The aggregation will let the objects live on when you dealloc them in the aggregating class. The composition in contrast will kill the objects on deallocation. There is actually no need to do that. It is a hint from the modeler to the programmer. So if you have some garbage collection on your own you might handle it differently.

When looking at the `ProductList` it feels wrong that it uses a composition. I guess the `Product` can live on its own. So an aggregation seems more appropriate. YMMV though.